# How to check Date Locales for Date Object

Tags: javascript, date, locale

In my browser

```
new Date("05/06/2013")
```

is treated as `M/D/YY`.  So above date will 5th of June.

I am using the US date format.  I believe JavaScript lets the browser decide the locale. But how do I check what locale the browser users at runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/2170192

Comment: Date parsing is almost entirely implementation dependent. For formats like the OP, most (all?) browsers will default to US format (m/d/y) for historical (not practical) reasons. The locale is used for output (e.g. [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.6)), not input. If you need to parse a string, do it yourself.